# Edit function doesn't work properly. Instead of update the data, it create a new entry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in C# and ASP.NET MVC. Instead of editing the entity, my code creates a new one when I press the button "update". Can you help me?

Here is the code - this is the view for edit:

```
@model Departments

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete department";
}

<div class="row text">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <p>
            <h1>Delete confirmation for @Model.Name</h1>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
               
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <img class="border-info" style="max-width:150px" id="PicturePreview" />

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="PictureURL" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="PictureURL" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span asp-validation-for="PictureURL" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" readonly />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form asp-action="Delete">
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="DepartmentId" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-danger float-right" />
                        </form>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" asp-action="Index">Show Departments</a>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var output = document.getElementById('PicturePreview');
            output.src = $("#PictureURL").val();
        })
    </script>
}
```

This is the controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using StudentInfo1.Data;
using StudentInfo1.Data.Services;
using StudentInfo1.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentInfo1.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDepartmentsService _service;

        public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentsService service)
        {
            _service=service;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var allDepartments = await _service.GetAllAsync();
           
            return View(allDepartments);
        }

        //Get : Departments - Create
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, PictureURL, Description")]Departments departments)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(departments);
            }

            await _service.AddAsync(departments);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        //Get: Departments - Details - ID
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
        {
            var departmentsDetails= await _service.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (departmentsDetails == null) 
                return View("NotFound");

            return View(departmentsDetails);
        }

        //Update
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var departmentsDetails = await _service.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (departmentsDetails == null) 
               return View("NotFound");
           
            return View(departmentsDetails);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("DepartmentId,Name,PictureURL,Description")] Departments departments)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(departments);
            }

            await _service.UpdateAsync(id, departments);

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        //Delete
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
            var departmentsDetails = await _service.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (departmentsDetails == null) 
               return View("NotFound");

            return View(departmentsDetails);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var departmentsDetails = await _service.GetByIdAsync(id);

            if (departmentsDetails == null) 
                return View("NotFound");

            await _service.DeleteAsync(id);
           
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}
```

The services

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using StudentInfo1.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentInfo1.Data.Services
{
    public class DepartmentsService : IDepartmentsService
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;

        public DepartmentsService(AppDbContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(Departments departments)
        {
            await _context.Departments.AddAsync(departments);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            var result = await _context.Departments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.DepartmentId == id);
            _context.Departments.Remove(result);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Departments>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var result = await _context.Departments.ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<Departments> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var result = await _context.Departments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.DepartmentId == id);
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<Departments> UpdateAsync(int id, Departments newDepartments)
        {
            _context.Update(newDepartments);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return newDepartments;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using StudentInfo1.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentInfo1.Data.Services
{
    public interface IDepartmentsService 
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Departments>> GetAllAsync();
        Task<Departments> GetByIdAsync(int id);
        Task AddAsync(Departments departments);
        Task<Departments> UpdateAsync(int id, Departments newDepartments);
        Task DeleteAsync(int id);
    }
}
```

This is the `index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Departments>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "List of Departments";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">

        <table class="table">
          <thead>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PictureURL)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <img class="rounded-top" src =" @item.PictureURL" alt="@item.Name" style="max-width: 200px" />
                        </td>
                        <td class ="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.DepartmentId">
                                <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>Edit
                            </a> |
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.DepartmentId">
                                <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>Details
                            </a> |
                            <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.DepartmentId">
                                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i>Delete
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position: fixed; right: 25px; bottom: 25px;" class="text-white">
     <a asp-controller="Departments" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-outline-succes">
         <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Add New </a>
</div>
```

In another project, I have similar code and it works...

Any idea what I should change?

Comment: That's a lot of code. What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code is impossible to follow. It seems you shared te page to delete the item, not to edit it. I'm missing a hidden field for the ID. Anyhow, usually to need to fetch the old model, apply the changes and save back the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR — **in the view, you're missing a hidden field for the `DepartmentId` property.** Add it and set it to the ID value of the entity being edited.

Here's why you're facing this issue:

1. The model binder tries to find a form field for `DepartmentId`. No such field exists, and `DepartmentId` is set to 0.
2. You call the `UpdateAsync` method of your service, and it calls the `Update` method of `DbContext`.
3. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-update(system-object)) states (in "Remarks"):

> <...> if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added state.

4. In Entity Framework, zero is interpreted as no value. That's why it puts the entity being edited into the `Added` state.
5. When generating query to the database, it creates an `INSERT` command (which adds new data) because of the `Added` state.

*Of course you can set the primary key property (`DepartmentId` in your case) to a value other than zero to fix this issue.* The entity with ID stored in `DepartmentId` will be updated.